# Merge 2 row value based on another common column in R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

so i have these 3 cols in total

```
col a      col b       col c
 500         NA         hello
 500         8          NA
```

Is there any way to make them together such as the output will be this?

```
col_a      col_b       col_c
 500         8         hello
```

What i've tried:

```
dt%>%
group_by(col_a) %>%
summarise_each(funs(first(na.omit(.))))
```

But it doesn't work! The result still stays the same :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: As per one of the user's request

This is the internal structure of my data frame :)

```
'data.frame':   11599 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col_a   : chr  "1" "1000" "10000" "10001" ...
 $ col_b   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ col_c   : chr  "tcpmux" "cadlock2" "ndmp" "scp-config" ...
```

and no in case you are wondering, col B indeed has values, not just NA all the way :P and col C has NA values even those it says there are strings over here

Edit no2: As per user request, this is the structure for 20 data.

```
structure(list(col_a = c("1", "1000", "10000", "10001", 
"10002", "10003", "10003", "10004", "10005", "10006", "10007", 
"10008", "10009", "10009 ", "10010", "10022 ", "10023", "10047 ", 
"10050", "10051"), 

col_b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "3", NA, "3", NA, "3", NA, NA),

col_c = c("tcpmux", "cadlock2", "ndmp", "scp-config", "documentum", "documentum_s", 
"documentum-s", "emcrmirccd", "emcrmird", "netapp-sync", "mvs-capacity", "octopus", 
"swdtp-sv", NA, "rxapi", NA, "cefd-vmp", NA, "zabbix-agent", "zabbix-trapper")),
.Names = c("col_a", "col_b", "col_c"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what does `any(is.na(df$colc))` produce?

Comment: Hi @Wietze314 I tried, and it produced True

Comment: Then I am not sure why NA values persist, except that for some col_a values there is only NA values in col_c.

Comment: hi @aichao After using your code, I tried to change the default to = "NA", since it returned an error(check your answer) that I've commented below, now all the data is replaced by NA string instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with `dplyr`, you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- dt %>% group_by(col_a=as.numeric(col_a)) %>%
              summarise_all(function(x) {first(na.omit(x), default=NA_character_)})
```

Using your posted data, we get:

```
print(res)
### A tibble: 19 x 3
##    col_a col_b          col_c
##    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>
##1       1               tcpmux
##2    1000             cadlock2
##3   10000                 ndmp
##4   10001           scp-config
##5   10002           documentum
##6   10003         documentum_s
##7   10004           emcrmirccd
##8   10005             emcrmird
##9   10006          netapp-sync
##10  10007         mvs-capacity
##11  10008              octopus
##12  10009     3       swdtp-sv
##13  10010  <NA>          rxapi
##14  10022     3           <NA>
##15  10023  <NA>       cefd-vmp
##16  10047     3           <NA>
##17  10050  <NA>   zabbix-agent
##18  10051  <NA> zabbix-trapper
```

Here we use `summaries_all` with a function that composes `first` and `na.omit`. Because all columns are characters, we specify `default=NA_character_` for `first`.

Now, I have no idea why if all elements for a group is `NA`, the result returns `""` (empty string) for the initial groups and (correctly as) `"<NA>"` after there are some groups with some non-`NA` data. To resolve that you can do an extra `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- dt %>% group_by(col_a=as.numeric(col_a)) %>%
              summarise_all(function(x) {first(na.omit(x), default=NA_character_)}) %>%
              mutate_all(function(x) {ifelse(x=="",NA_character_,x)})
### A tibble: 19 x 3
##    col_a col_b          col_c
##    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>
##1       1  <NA>         tcpmux
##2    1000  <NA>       cadlock2
##3   10000  <NA>           ndmp
##4   10001  <NA>     scp-config
##5   10002  <NA>     documentum
##6   10003  <NA>   documentum_s
##7   10004  <NA>     emcrmirccd
##8   10005  <NA>       emcrmird
##9   10006  <NA>    netapp-sync
##10  10007  <NA>   mvs-capacity
##11  10008  <NA>        octopus
##12  10009     3       swdtp-sv
##13  10010  <NA>          rxapi
##14  10022     3           <NA>
##15  10023  <NA>       cefd-vmp
##16  10047     3           <NA>
##17  10050  <NA>   zabbix-agent
##18  10051  <NA> zabbix-trapper
```

Comment: hi @aichao I got this error Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  Don't know how to generate default for object of class character . All my data frame are of character data type. I am not sure whether that affects or not.

Comment: @Wietze314: what data are you running on?

Comment: `df <- data.frame(cola=c(500,500), colb=c(NA,8), colc=c("hello",NA),stringsAsFactors=F)` but it suddenly seems to work. I remove my previous comment.

Comment: Then change my `group_by(col_a)` to `group_by(cola)` and it should work.

Comment: @user127886: please see my edit. The issue is with specifying a `default` for `first` if there all elements are `NA` and omitted. In this case, we set `default=NA`.

Comment: hi @aichao I got an error: Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : expecting a string

Comment: @user127886: there is something in your data that we don't know about. Please examine my latest edit. Here, all my columns are characters with some NAs. Please see if it works on the **data I posted**.

Comment: hi @aichao I just tested your data and it worked perfectly, I am still unsure why my data is not working. I will try again, thanks!

Comment: I know this is a pain, but can you post 20 rows of your data in your question using `dput(dt[1:20,])`?

Comment: Hi @aichao no worries, its not a pain, I am asking clarification for my doubt, so its actually a hassle on your part to help me, thank you! Done :)

Comment: @user127886: please see my edit. Now, you should not get the error, even with your full data, but there is that issue with the empty string instead of "<NA>" that I will work on. BTW, if you just want the empty string, then you can use `""` instead of `NA_character_` for the `default`.

Comment: Hi @aichao It's confusing how some of the rows are now empty while some of the rows are still returning NA value after execution of your code (But the duplication issue still exist). I am really sorry, and thank you for taking your time to do this.

Comment: Hi @user127886, in case you still care, I've updated to remove the empty strings in the result. What is the duplication issue?

Comment: Hi @aichao The duplication issue is the one that we are all trying to solve - to combine the values together into the same row based on the column name, and of course I care, and thanks for the time invested too. Appreciated

Comment: @user127886: Does my last edit solve your question, at all? That is, is the output what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @aichao Unfortunately no, if you see #12 and #13 of the data, I actually want them to be combined together as a single row because of the same column name in COL A (1009) so the output will be 3 for col B and swdtp-sv for C. The rows are still duplicated and not combined.

Comment: Hi @user127886: sorry I missed that. One way to fix that is to convert `col_a` to numeric before grouping (because it is numeric). Another way (if you want to keep it as characters) is to trim the string to get rid of any training (or preceding) white spaces. Please see my edit and let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: @aichao omg thank you! You don't know how much of a help you are to me!! That could have taken me ages to figure out. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @user127886: Glad to help! I learned a few things myself concerning `first` and character vectors working on this.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` I just use the `max` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(cola=c(500,500), colb=c(NA,8), colc=c("hello",NA),stringsAsFactors=F)

df %>% group_by(cola) %>% summarise_all(max, na.rm=T)
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
cola  colb  colc
<dbl> <dbl> <chr>
  1   500     8 hello
```

Comment: Hi @Wietze314 the merging doesn't work. After using your solution, it removed the col b NA value while col C value still has its NA value too

Comment: If i run the sample in my answer, it gives the result in my answer. You're data may be formatted differently. Maybe in `colc` there are no true `NA` but just a string that says 'NA' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try (without the plyr package):

```
df <- data.frame(cola=c(500,500), colb=c(NA,8), colc=c("hello",NA),stringsAsFactors=F)
aggregate(df[,c(2,3)], by=list(cola=df$cola), function(xx) xx[!is.na(xx)])
```

Comment: Hi @Bastien All the NA character changed to character(0) and nothing else changed after applying your code. :(

Comment: By looking at the new data you post, we can see your data do not pair perfectly NA not-NA (see col_a == 10003).  That will be a problem. My solution won't work in that case, not sure about other commenters solution's.

Comment: Also, you have col_a=="10009" and col_a=="10009 ".  Those things are totaly different for R.  Making it not able to aggregate.  Looks to me like your data is super messy.  Clean it and try the different solutions we provided.  That's your problem

Comment: Hi @Bastien I don't see any -NA around in col_a == 10003. Anyway thank you for your time :)

Comment: look at col_c for col_a == 10003, you'll see 2 entries with a slight difference (documentum_s vs documentum-s) and no value in col_b.  My code do the right thing in that situation, however it's messy and not what you want. It put character(0) because there is no col_b value (other than NA)